# how to understand the structure of a neural network

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network

I have a deep learning structure designed for the critic within the actor critic reinforcement learning as follows:

```
class Critic_MLP(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, args, critic_input_dim):
        super(Critic_MLP, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(critic_input_dim, args.mlp_hidden_dim)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(args.mlp_hidden_dim, args.mlp_hidden_dim)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(args.mlp_hidden_dim, 1)
        self.activate_func = [nn.Tanh(), nn.ReLU()][args.use_relu]

    def forward(self, critic_input):
        x = self.activate_func(self.fc1(critic_input))
        x = self.activate_func(self.fc2(x))
        value = self.fc3(x)
        return value
```

where `args.use_relu` has value `False`. Could anyone tell me how to understand `self.acivate_func` where two activation functions are included with a Boolean value outside the bracket?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`args.use_relu` is a `bool` that is used as an index on a the list `[nn.Tanh(), nn.ReLU()]`. Python [automatically converts](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=bool%20int#boolean-values) it to an integer: `0` for `False` and `1` for `True`.

This is an opaque but concise way of saying

```py
if args.use_relu:
  self.activate_func = nn.ReLU()
else:
  self.activate_func = nn.Tanh()
```